# How to filter out numbers with specific digits?

Tags: python

I wanna do this: There is a number N. How many numbers are there smaller than N, which contains the 0 or 4 or 7 digits  only ?
For example.: N = 50, the good numbers are: 0,4,7,40,44,47. total_count = 6

```
db = 0
badnums = '1235689'
lsgood = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    szamok = [int(j) for j in str(i)]
    for i in szamok:
        if str(i) not in badnums:
            lsgood.append(i)
            db += 1
print(lsgood,db)
```

Comment: Why is 44 not a possibility?

Comment: For the future, please state your problem clearly. I only realized what the problem is after I tried out your code. Please post a comparison expected vs. actual output for this kind of question.

Comment: I just built a solution to exclude the 44...

Comment: Yes I forgot 44, sry 0,4,7,40,44,47 are the good numbers.

Comment: I added solutions for both cases, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code. In that case, it always helps to step thourgh it either by hand or with the help of a debugger (as it is integrated in many IDEs). Lets take a look at your code:

```
n = 50
db = 0
badnums = '1235689'
lsgood = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    szamok = [int(j) for j in str(i)]
    for i in szamok:
        if str(i) not in badnums:
            lsgood.append(i)
            db += 1
print(lsgood,db)
```

The first think that should jump to your eye is the reusage of the variable name `i`. You shouldn't do that, so we rename the variable `j`

```
n = 50
db = 0
badnums = '1235689'
lsgood = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    szamok = [int(j) for j in str(i)]
    for j in szamok:
        if str(j) not in badnums:
            lsgood.append(?)
            db += 1
print(lsgood,db)
```

But now we have the first interesting mistake. What do we want to append to `lsgood`? you added the inner `i`, which was always a single digit. This meant, that `lsgood` only contained single digits, which is not what you wanted. So, we add `i`:

```
n = 50
db = 0
badnums = '1235689'
lsgood = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    szamok = [int(j) for j in str(i)]
    for j in szamok:
        if str(j) not in badnums:
            lsgood.append(i)
            db += 1
print(lsgood,db)
```

Now we get the following output:

```
[0, 4, 7, 10, 14, 17, 20, 24, 27, 30, 34, 37, 40, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 48, 49, 50] 26
```

These are way to many. If we look closely, It counts all numbers containing at least one of '047'. That is not what we want. So we start to look into it and discover the magic that is [`else` on `for`-loops](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html).

```
n = 50
db = 0
badnums = '1235689'
lsgood = []
for i in range(0, n + 1):
    szamok = [int(j) for j in str(i)]
    for j in szamok:
        if str(j) in badnums:
            break # The number contains a bad digit, we don't want it
    else:
        lsgood.append(i) # All digits past the test, it only contains good digits
        db += 1
print(lsgood, db)
```

This gives the intended output:

```
[0, 4, 7, 40, 44, 47] 6
```

As others showed, this can be shortened significantly, but I think for a beginner, this is the easier to understand solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression like this:

```
sum(1 for i in range(n + 1) if all(d in '047' for d in str(i)))
```

This returns: 6

Note that this includes the number 44, which your expected output does not.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over all numbers less than `n` may not be the most efficient if `n` is large (though I haven't done any timings; this would be worth doing if performance matters). Instead, we can just generate numbers that are probably valid (all numbers with the same number of digits as `n` but only using 0, 4, or 7) and then eliminate any that aren't (those greater than `n`).

```py
from itertools import product

def n_good(n: int = 50, allowed_digits: str = "047") -> int:
    n_digits = len(str(n))
    possible_nums = [int("".join(num)) for num in product(set(allowed_digits + "0"), repeat=n_digits)]
    if "0" not in allowed_digits:
        possible_nums = [num for num in possible_nums if "0" not in str(num)]
    return sum(1 for num in possible_nums if num < n)

assert n_good(50) == 6 and n_good(50, "47") == 4
```

EDIT: I did a couple of quick timings compared to one of the other answers:

```py
def n_good_range(n):
    return sum(1 for i in range(n + 1) if all(d in '047' for d in str(i)))
```

```
| n            | 10_000           | 100_000          | 1_000_000         |
| ------------ | ---------------- | ---------------- | ----------------- |
| n_good       | 138 µs ± 9.48 µs | 464 µs ± 44.3 µs | 1.28 ms ± 42.5 µs |
| n_good_range | 9.05 ms ± 319 µs | 91.5 ms ± 4.4 ms | 942 ms ± 57.9 ms  |
```

(timings done using `%%timeit` in IPython)

EDIT2: based on @Jan's insightful comment, I fixed the function to work even when 0 is not one of the allowed digits. This will make things slightly slower sometimes, but I found that `n_good(1_000_000, "47")` only took 1.7 ms (compared with 1.3 ms for `n_good(1_000_000, "047")`).

Comment: Really good answer, several orders of magnitude faster than the "naive" solution counting up, since this is basically `O(log(n))` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: This solution can be somewhat sped up by using [PEP 572 Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), and thus avoiding the summation. For `n = 1_000_000` and using Python 3.8.0a4, I get `500 loops, best of 5: 891 usec per loop` without using Assignment Expressions, and `500 loops, best of 5: 850 usec per loop` when using Assignment Expressions.

Comment: I continued to think about your solution, and it does not work properly if `0` is **not** included in the given set of digits, e.g. check `n_good(500, '47')`. In that case you will not generate the numbers with "leading zeros". You need to modify this solution to always add the `0` to the set of digits, and after processing remove all integers which contain a zero, since after converting the strings to integers the leading zeros will disappear, and thus all zeros will be trailing zeros which we then remove. This will not affect the asymptotic speed of this algorithm, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Jan Ah, good catch, I didn't realize that. I've just updated with a solution that I think should work for any set of allowed digits. It just does the simplest check: after converting to ints (so the leading 0s vanish), filter out numbers with 0s still present. Thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using `set`s:

```
n = 50

lsgood = []
for i in range(n):
    if set(list(str(i))).issubset(list('047')):
        lsgood.append(i)

print(lsgood, len(lsgood))

# [0, 4, 7, 40, 44, 47] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` (only works properly for two digits)

This solution uses `combinations_with_replacement` from the `itertools` module, since we are looking for all combinations of digits smaller than the target value `n`, with repeatable digits. Since `combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2)` returns `AA AB AC BB BC CC`, and thus considers `BA == AB`, we have to add all the digits to the back of the string, to cover the other combination pairing as well, i.e. we use `'047047'` instead of `'047'` internally.

This solution avoids looping over all values, which can be more efficient for large `N`. Instead we only have `log10(n)` python loops:

```
def good_digits(n, digs='047'):
    import itertools

    digs = digs + digs[-2::-1]
    l = len(str(n)) 
    s = set(int("".join(i)) for j in range(1,l+1) for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(digs, j)) 
    return sum(1 for i in s if i < n)

good_digits(50, '047') # 6
```

### Python 3.8 Assignment Expressions

Using [Python 3.8 Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), we can avoid the summing of the values in the set, at the cost of the assignment expression:

```
def good_digits_38(n, digs='047'):
    import itertools

    digs = digs + digs[-2::-1]
    l = len(str(n)) 
    s = set(r for j in range(1,l+1) for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(digs, j) if (r:=int("".join(i))) < n) 
    return len(s)

good_digits_38(50, '047') # 6
```

### Permutations

If you want the permutations instead of combinations with replacement, e.g. excluding "44", use this solution for permutations:

```
def good_digits_perm(n, digs='047'):
    import itertools

    l = len(str(n)) 
    s = set(int("".join(i)) for j in range(1,l+1) for i in itertools.permutations(digs, j))
    return sum(1 for i in s if i < n)

good_digits_perm(50, '047') # 5
```

Comment: Your solution does seem the fastest =) however, I think one of us has a bug. If you run both of our functions with `n = 500`, we disagree. I'll check who's right, hold on.

Comment: It seems like your solution is missing 404 and 407 when `n = 500`?

Comment: I will check for 500.

Comment: @Nathan You are right, this solution only works for two digits. For three digits we have to "blow up" the padding of the digits much more (basically doing `digs = digs * len(n)`, making this much slower than yours.